# Excel - Total cell from certain worksheets in same workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know I can do this in vba but I am trying to see if there are formulas I can use so I do not have to have a macro enabled workbook.

I have a workbook that contains a monthly tab (named MONTHLY), a week tab for each week (named week 1, week2, etc) and a day tab for each day (named d_20200601, d_20200602, etc). (note there will be an unknown number of week tabs and day tabs).

I am trying to total up the days in the week tab and total up the weeks in the month tab - but since I will not know how many week and day tabs there will be, I need to include all the ones that start with "week" and "d_". I can do this in vba, but I wanted to know if anyone has coded something similar with out vba.

Also of note, since the day sheets are added daily and the latest day is at the end, the week 1 sheet will contain the total of the first 7 day sheets, week 2 will be the next 7 and so on.

Comment: You may be able to use a 3D Sum: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sum-multiple-worksheets.

Comment: I saw that yesterday...but (from what I can see) it needs to know the names of the sheets up front.  In my case, the daily sheets get an additional sheet added every day.  from what I can tell, 3D Sum formulas would have to manually be changed each day.

Comment: One trick is to use a hidden sheet at the beginning and another at the end, and reference those in your 3D formula. All the sheets to be summed will be in the middle, so you won't refer to them by name.

Comment: That just may work!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per BigBen,

You could setup your sheets like this:
[image]

This will work for Jan & Feb totals with formulas like this: =Sum(JanStart:JanEnd!A1)
However you can't use a sum to get the Yearly totals you would have to do a =Jan!A1+Feb!A1...
However if you rearrange your columns like this:
[image]
You can now get your yearly totals with: =SUM(Jan:JanStart!A1)
You can also eliminate some of the helper sheets as you Don't need End of Month sheets since you can total from JanStart:FebStart!A1, etc., to get the Month totals.

HTH